# Why is my setState method failing to change my containers background colors?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to change the background color of 4 different containers when they are tapped individually. For some reason I can run the method `setBoardColors` which uses `setState` and all the background colors are changed and everything works fine however when someone taps one of the containers and the `setSquareColor` method is called which also uses `setState` I get the error *NoSuchMethodError: Class 'Color' has no instance method '[]='*.

Here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'set state example',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

Color myOrange = const Color.fromRGBO(255, 140, 66, 1.00);
Color myBlue = const Color.fromRGBO(26, 83, 92, 0.87);
Color myRed = const Color.fromRGBO(255, 107, 107, 0.87);
Color myGold = const Color.fromRGBO(255, 230, 109, 1.00);
Color myGreen = const Color.fromRGBO(32, 191, 85, 1.00);

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  var squareColor = [
    myOrange,
    myOrange,
    myOrange,
    myOrange,
  ];

  void setBoardColors() {
    setState(() {
      squareColor[0] = myBlue;
      squareColor[1] = myRed;
      squareColor[2] = myGold;
      squareColor[3] = myGreen;
    });
  }

  void setSquareColor(squareIndex, squareColor) {
    setState(() {
      print("setSquareColor called");
      squareColor[squareIndex] = squareColor;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    setBoardColors();

    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          width: 200.0,
          height: 200.0,
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  //square index 0
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      setSquareColor(0, myOrange);
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      width: 100.0,
                      height: 100.0,
                      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                        color: squareColor[0],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  //square index 1
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      setSquareColor(1, myOrange);
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      width: 100.0,
                      height: 100.0,
                      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                        color: squareColor[1],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  //square index 2
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      setSquareColor(2, myOrange);
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      width: 100.0,
                      height: 100.0,
                      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                        color: squareColor[2],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  //square index 3
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      setSquareColor(3, myOrange);
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      width: 100.0,
                      height: 100.0,
                      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                        color: squareColor[3],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same variable name, for the parameter of the function and your array "squareColor". I suggest you change the array of colors to "squareColors":

```
var squareColors = [
    myOrange,
    myOrange,
    myOrange,
    myOrange,
  ];

  void setBoardColors() {
    setState(() {
      squareColors[0] = myBlue;
      squareColors[1] = myRed;
      squareColors[2] = myGold;
      squareColors[3] = myGreen;
    });
  }

  void setSquareColor(squareIndex, squareColor) {
    setState(() {
      print("setSquareColor called");
      squareColors[squareIndex] = squareColor;
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, this resolved the NoSuchMethodError however the containers still aren't changing color when clicked.

Comment: in your onTap function you are setting them all to myOrange, so change it to the correct colors

Comment: I don't follow, I'm trying to change the container's colors to myOrange when they are tapped. They start off as different colors - myBlue, myRed, myGold, and myGreen.

Comment: okay I found your problem, you are calling setBoardColors(); at the beginning 
of the build function when you should be calling it only on the initState function. everytime you call setState it will call your build function again which will in your case call setBoardColors() again